# What is the: 'Bfrtip' on datatable

Tags: jquery, datatables

What is the: 'Bfrtip', in the datatable? I read the documentation, but it was not clear to me what this really does?

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('#na_datatable').DataTable({
        "order": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
        dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
          'print'
        ]
    });
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by gift, but each letter corresponds to an element of the datatable. Try removing and re-adding some of the letters to see elements disappear and re-appear.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed a question.

Comment: Yep, as @mark_b says, each letter is an element, more documentation here: https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The [dom](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom) option for DataTables *"Defines the table control elements to appear on the page and in what order"*.

For `Bfrtip`, the following options are set:

- B - Buttons
- f - Filtering input
- r - Processing display element
- t - The table
- i - Table information summary
- p - Pagination control